# How to know the middle of a LineShape

Tags: c#, forms, math, point

I have a `LineShape` in my form and I need that when clicked a label appears exactly in the middle of this line, what is the math I should do to determinate this middle point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`LineShape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.lineshape.aspx) exposes its coordinates with `X1`, `X2`, `Y1` and `Y2`. Finding the center of it is basic geometry:

```
LineShape line = /*...*/;
Label label = /*..*/;

// calculate the center of the line
var center = new Point((line.X1 + line.X2) / 2, (line.Y1 + line.Y2) / 2);

// center the label on the line
label.Top = center.Y - label.Height / 2
label.Left = center.X - label.Width / 2
```

Comment: The final step would be to set the label's `Location.X` and `Location.Y` to the values of `x` and `y` that @Xiaoy312 mentioned above.

Comment: @Sylverac Actually, that doesn't center the label on the line, but it centers the top-left corner of the label on the line.

Comment: Ahh yes, I forgot that the position's origin is at the top-left corner.

Comment: I had already centered the label, I just needed the center of the line, the first code was enough but now may help others as well